# Web Services in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I am trying to learn to write web services involving `PHP / MySQL`.
I would want to post some data from client to server and then store it into a MySQL database via a web service.

I'm very new to this area.

I tried googling but did not find any basic tutorials. All of them were fancy and hi fi involving `SOAP` etc.

Can someone give me a start by posing a code snippet / suggesting a decent URL / suggesting a good book to start with.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing the SOAP results because you are googling "web service".  I'm not sure that word means what you think it means.  If you just want PHP to create a new record in MySQL then including "web service" in your search is going to give you more complex results than you would otherwise want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>For basic tutorials in several web-related languages, please start at [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/)</strike>

There are several good websites to learn HTML from. For example, [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/).

In basic terms, what you need to do it build a form in HTML that sends the data to a PHP script that then processes the information and stores it in a database.

Comment: Also, I very strongly recommend learning at least one MVC framework, like Symfony, CodeIgniter, Zend Framework or Yii. Or, if you're not committed to PHP, I think Rails is significantly better than any of those.

Comment: i was trying to make it way more complicated than it actually is.. thanks for he answer:P